# Issues with API call

Tags: php, api, curl

I am creating a quiz web app using [Open trivia DB API](https://opentdb.com/api_config.php) and PHP. The issue I'm, having now is checking whether the option a user selected is the correct answer. I realized that the program is making another API call and getting a different set of questions entirely everytime so the options being checked with the selected options are totally different. Is there I can store the first result of the API and then check the selected with it instead of making a new call every time?

This is my Controller

```
public function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
    $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'APIKEY:xxxxxx',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}

    public function quiz()
    {
        $get_data= $this->callAPI('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18', false);
$data = json_decode($get_data, true);
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
            {
              $sum = 0;  
                 foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                 {
                    foreach ($value as $key => $k)
                    {
                        if($_POST[$key]== $k['correct_answer'])
                        {
                            $sum++;
                        }
                        
echo"The question is ".$k['question']."you answered  $_POST[$key] and the correct answer is  ". $k['correct_answer']. " Your score is $sum"; // I used this line to find out that the problem.
                    }
                    
                 }
  
                    }
        else
        {
        $this->view('quiz', $data);
        }
    }
```

This is my view

```
<div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card ">
    <form class="my-auto" id ="regForm" method="POST" action="">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                 <?
                 foreach ($data as $key => $value):
                    foreach ($value as $key => $k):?>
                         <div class="tab">
                             <span><p><? echo $key+1  ?></p></span>
                             <h4 class="card-title"> <? echo $k["question"] .  "<br>";?></h4>
                                 <? foreach ( $k["incorrect_answers"] as $incorrect):
                               ?>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="<? echo $key ?>" value="<? echo " $incorrect"; ?>"> <? echo " $incorrect"; ?>
    
</div>
                    <?endforeach ?>
                   <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rad2" name="<? echo "$key" ?>" value="<? echo $k["correct_answer"]; ?>"> <? echo  $k["correct_answer"]; ?> 
                   
                <div style="overflow:auto;">
                    <div style="float:right;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-fw" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                     <button type="button"class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-fw" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                    </div>
             </div>
         </div> 
         
    <?endforeach ?>
 <?endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Any help I can get will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did (does) this script ever function properly?  It appears there are multiple errors.   Also unless there is more documentation other than the link you gave, there are many more issues.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` to temporarily store such small bits of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you are doing an API request, render a page with questions and then when the user submits the answers want to re-use the result from the original API confirm that the answer is correct?

As the api does not allow you to retrieve the same questions using a request hash or question ID's, you will need to introduce a layer into your code that stores the information from the API request for use in the next request.

The easiest solution, looking at your coding level, would be to start using the $_SESSION global to store the array for questions into the session, then when the user submits their answers check for this session information.

Although I think you should have enough to look at documentation and move further, let's tear this down a little bit:

```
        public function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
    $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method){
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'APIKEY:xxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    curl_close($curl);
    $_SESSION['quizQuestions'] = $result;
    return $result;
}

public function quiz()
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" && isset($_SESSION['quizQuestions']))
    {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['quizQuestions'] as $key => $value)
        {
            foreach ($value as $key => $k)
            {
                if($_POST[$key]== $k['correct_answer'])
                {
                    $sum++;
                }

                echo"The question is ".$k['question']."you answered  $_POST[$key] and the correct answer is  ". $k['correct_answer']. " Your score is $sum"; // I used this line to find out that the problem.
            }

        }
        $_SESSION['quizQuestions'] = null;
        // render view..
    }
    else
    {
        $get_data= $this->callAPI('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18', false);
        $data = json_decode($get_data, true);
        $this->view('quiz', $data);
    }
}
```

This obviously needs more work, but I hope you get the gist. Please also notice the fix in `$_POST[key]` key would be seen as a constant, not a variable.

Comment: That `$_POST[key]` would not be a constant.  It would be a fatal error.  You did well here.  Personally I do not use session variables.  Over the years I have found the to be unreliable.  Just like cookies.  I do not like to depend on Browsers and the Browser's  cookie settings.  I have NEVER has a problem with saving JSON and retrieving JSON. with file_get/put_contents().  You fixed the code but ignored all the bad practices.   When I see the script switching back and forth between  PHP and HTML more, I cringe. That goes against PHP best practices. You put band-aids on poor programming.

Comment: @Misunderstood, I absolutely agree with all you said. But providing code that isn't too dinstinct from what the OP has, helps them understand the difference in thinking and providing a simple path in becoming better. Would I have provided a complete rewrite with PSR packages, CACHE adapters, Guzzle and its Middlewares would have very likely demotivated OP into understanding what to improve and potentially reduce likelihood of OP moving forward. Thanks for your answer, it gives a great improved example of conventions and improvements.

Comment: @Luceos Ahh.... Session! i forgot that. Thank you for pointing that out. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You question lacks clarity.  I assume it should have said

> I do an API request to get questions and answers.  I create an HTML
> page with a `<form>` to ask the questions.  The form then does a post
> request to a script where I check the answers.  I need to store the
> answers to use when the player submits their answer.

According to the API documentation in your link, you can only do a GET request.
So the post fields are not applicable.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Accept: application/json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=multiple'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
var_export($response);
```

The above returns this:

```
    array (
  'response_code' => 0,
  'results' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'In golf, what name is given to a hole score of two under par?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Eagle',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Birdie',
        1 => 'Bogey',
        2 => 'Albatross',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'How many soccer players should be on the field at the same time?',
      'correct_answer' => '22',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => '20',
        1 => '24',
        2 => '26',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Who won the 2015 Formula 1 World Championship?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Lewis Hamilton',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Nico Rosberg',
        1 => 'Sebastian Vettel',
        2 => 'Jenson Button',
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'When was the first official international game played?',
      'correct_answer' => '1872',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => '1880',
        1 => '1863',
        2 => '1865',
      ),
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Which boxer was banned for taking a bite out of Evander Holyfield\'s ear in 1997?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Mike Tyson',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Roy Jones Jr.',
        1 => 'Evander Holyfield',
        2 => 'Lennox Lewis',
      ),
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Which African American is in part responsible for integrating Major League baseball?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Jackie Robinson',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Curt Flood',
        1 => 'Roy Campanella',
        2 => 'Satchell Paige',
      ),
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Who won the premier league title in the 2015-2016 season following a fairy tale run?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Leicester City',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Tottenham Hotspur',
        1 => 'Watford',
        2 => 'Stoke City',
      ),
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Who did Steven Gerrard win the Champions League with?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Liverpool',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Real Madrid',
        1 => 'Chelsea',
        2 => 'Man City',
      ),
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'Which country will host the 2022 FIFA World Cup?',
      'correct_answer' => 'Qatar',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => 'USA',
        1 => 'Japan',
        2 => 'Switzerland',
      ),
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'category' => 'Sports',
      'type' => 'multiple',
      'difficulty' => 'easy',
      'question' => 'In the 2014 FIFA World Cup, what was the final score in the match Brazil - Germany?',
      'correct_answer' => '1-7',
      'incorrect_answers' => 
      array (
        0 => '1-5',
        1 => '1-6',
        2 => '2-6',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I do not understand this:

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is superfluous. 
It was not clear this was the player posting answers. 
If there was no post, the script would not be running.

If you are using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` as if your curl request will will set the value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`, it will not.

This is wrong.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'APIKEY:xxxxxx',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
```

`Content-Type: application/json` is incorrect unless you have more documentation that is in your link. 
What the API doc says is

> Use of this API does not require a API Key, just generate the URL
> below use it in your own application to retrieve trivia questions.

And I could find no documentation that the request should be JSON.
The only request format I could find was this:

```
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=21&difficulty=medium&type=multiple
```

That is not a POST request, a JSON request, or a PUT request.
It is a GET request.

The way you unpack the result nested array is problematic. 
This is incorrect.

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value){
   foreach ($value as $key => $k){
```

It should probably look like this ($key is only used once)

```
 foreach ($data as $value){
   foreach ($value as $key => $k){
```

Still the first foreach should look like this:

```
foreach($data['results'] as $key => list(,,,$question,$correctAnswer,$incorrectAnswers){
  $data[$key]['question'] = $question; 
  $data[$key]['correctAnswer'] = $correctAnswer; 
  $data[$key]['incorrectAnserers'] = $incorrectAnswers;
```

}
You should have a player id, save the questions and answers with their id.
I often use their ip address as the user id.

```
$id= intval(str_replace('.','',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$jsn = json_encode($data,true);
file_put_contents("$id.jsn",$jsn);
```

Then make the HTML form for the questions. 
You really should have included the HTML for the form where the player enters their answers. So I will use a very simplified form.  You then drop `$form` in the questions  HTML

```
$form = '';
$form ."<form action="#" method="post>";
foreach($data as $number =>  list($question,$correctAnswer,$choices){
   $choices[] = $correctAnswer;
   shuffle($choices);
   $form .= "Q$number: $question<br>\n";
   $form .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a$number\"  /> $choice[0]<br>\n";
   $form .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a$number\"  /> $choice[1]<br>\n";       
   $form .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a$number\"  /> $choice[2]<br>\n";       
   $form .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a$number\"  /> $choice[3]<br>\n";
}
$form .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value="$id\"\n";
$form .= "</form><br>\n";
```

Then when the answers are submitted get the questions and answers again.

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("$is.jsn"),true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am a newbie in programming and code shows the level of my understanding at the moment.  What i meant by this ` $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is if the the form is submitted (via POST method) then execute the following blocks of code. But if the request method is `GET` (getting the html form` then do this `else
    {
        $get_data= $this->callAPI('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18', false);
        $data = json_decode($get_data, true);
        $this->view('quiz', $data);
    }`

Comment: Also, for the `callAPI` function. I was hoping to use it for all API calls (POST, GET, PUT etc) hence why i included the switch statement.

Comment: And for the loop `foreach ($data as $key => $value){ foreach ($value as $key => $k){.....}` You are absolutely right. I have corrected it as you suggested. Thanks again.